# scala way to segregate each type of object in Array[Seq[Object]], to seperate object reference

Tags: scala

PFB case classes

```
class TypeData()

case class delivery(accept_language:String,customer_id:String) extends TypeData

case class junk(`type`:String) extends TypeData
```

I have an object "check" which is of type `Array[Seq[TypeData]]` and sample data looks like below,

```
Array[Seq[TypeData]] = Array(ArrayBuffer(delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(open), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(injection), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), junk(click), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), junk(injection), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), junk(open), junk(injection), deli...
```

now i would like to know, how to segregate each object type data to have its own reference. example,

```
val delivery_data = Seq[delivery]  (should contain only delivery type data) (delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035), delivery(null,1035)....) and similarly

val junk_data = Seq[junk] (should contain only junk type data)
(junk(injection), junk(click), junk(injection)
```

Regards,
Satyajit.

Comment: Formatted code from this post

Comment: You should use `Option[String]` instead `null` for nullable values.

Answer (score 1):

```
val a: Array[Seq[TypeData]] = ???

val (deliveries, junks) = 
  a.flatten.foldLeft((Seq.empty[delivery], Seq.empty[junk])) {
    case ((d, j), e: delivery) => (d :+ e, j)
    case ((d, j), e: junk) => (d, j :+ e)
  }
```

If you want to collect only deliveries or only junks, the following way is for this:

```
val deliveries = a.flatten collect {
  case d: delivery => d
}
```

or

```
val junks = a.flatten collect {
  case j: junk => j
}
```

Comment: Have another additional question in continuation to above,
How do i segregate the data, in case my data now looks like below,

Array[Seq[String,object]], example Array(ArrayBuffer("delivery",obj1),("junk",obj2),("delivery",obj3).....etc

Answer (score 1):

```
val data: Array[Seq[TypeData]] = ???

data(0).partition(_.isInstanceOf[delivery])
```

Comment: This will work but is not type-safe. The other answer is the more "proper" way to do it...